# Implementing git server which uses username and password to authenticate

Tags: git

I use 2 different machines to code every once in a while, and I was thinking about implementing a git server on my Raspberry Pi.

First of all, what's your best tutorial on handling all of the configuration and rights management?

Second, I want to authenticate with username and password combo when pushing and pulling, but I haven't found a way to do this, yet.

Right now I have a clean install of git-core.

Comment: Try [gitolite](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/).

Answer (score 2):

As git is a `Distributed version control system` you don't need an extra configuration to install a *git server* because actually there is no server or rather each repo could act as one. So the next steps would be enough

- Install git in your *server* and create the repository there. Create bare repositories so that you can push to them. (As patthoyts explains on his comment)
- Add this remote machine to the git-remotes in your local computers `git remote add origin ssh://user@host/git/example` (for a normal ssh configuration)
- Grant ssh access to the local machines (take a look at an ssh tutorial in order to configure how to use Keys and avoid having to introduce user and pass every time)
- From now on use this server as you would use github or whatever

Comment: +1 but note that the port number will normally be 22 for ssh and is not required for a standard configuration. Normally: git ls-remote ssh://userid@host/path/to/repository.git. And on the server machine, create *bare* repositories so that you can push to them.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but like I already said in my post, I am explicitly looking for a solution based on username/password authentication. I do not want to have to fiddle around with ssh keys when I grant a friend access to a server through a special 'public' user account.